# Creating SQL Query For Matches and Non Matches

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables involved in an SQL query I am trying to figure out how to write.

**itemmeta**

```
order_item_id       meta_key            meta_value
------------------- ------------------  -------------------
1                   _subscription_test  0
1                   _subscription_more  0
1                   _product_id         100
2                   _subscription_test  0
2                   _subscription_more  0
2                   _product_id         100
3                   _product_id         100
```

**order_items**

```
order_item_id       order_id
------------------- ------------------
1                   200
2                   201
3                   202
```

**postmeta***

```
order_id            meta_key
------------------  ------------------
200                 _original_order
```

The query should do the following:

1. Find itemmeta.order_item_id

   ```
   Where itemmeta.meta_key LIKE '_subscription%' 
      OR itemmeta.meta_key LIKE '_recurring%'
   ```

   -> use only unique values from here
2. Take those itemmeta.order_item_id values and match to order_items.order_item_id
   -> return order_items.order_id
3. Take those order_items.order_id and match to postmeta.post_id where postmeta.meta_key does NOT have a match for '_original_order'
   (throw out any order_ids where that meta key exists)
4. Those those results, reference back to itemmeta.order_item_id and find the ones where itemmeta.meta_key = '_product_id' 
   -> return itemmeta.meta_value

**Final result:**

```
order_items.order_id, order_itemmeta.meta_value (_product_id)
```

So in the above tables this would return 1 row:

```
  order_id => 201
  meta_value => 100
```

I'm not quite sure on the merges and negatives needed to perform this query.  Would appreciate any assistance someone might be able to provide!

Comment: Have you tried to write such query?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work?

```
SELECT order_id, meta_value FROM 
(
  SELECT oi.order_id, oi.order_item_id FROM order_items oi
  LEFT JOIN postmeta pm ON oi.order_id = pm.order_id
  WHERE oi.order_item_id IN (SELECT im.order_item_id FROM itemmeta im WHERE im.meta_key LIKE '_subscription%' OR im.meta_key LIKE '_recurring%')
  AND oi.order_id NOT IN (SELECT pm.order_id FROM postmeta pm WHERE pm.meta_key = '_original_order')
) subquery 
INNER JOIN itemmeta im ON subquery.order_item_id = im.order_item_id
WHERE im.meta_key = '_product_id'
```

When testing with this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f307/2) it gives this result:

```
ORDER_ID    META_VALUE
201         100
```

It's early in the morning where I am though and I obviously haven't tested it that thoroughly so no guarantees ;)

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution

```
SELECT i.order_id, m.meta_value
  FROM
(
  SELECT order_item_id,
         MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_product_id' THEN meta_value END) meta_value
    FROM itemmeta
   WHERE meta_key LIKE '_subscription%' 
      OR meta_key LIKE '_recurring%'
      OR meta_key = '_product_id'
   GROUP BY order_item_id
  HAVING MAX(meta_key LIKE '_subscription%')
       + MAX(meta_key LIKE '_recurring%') > 0
) m JOIN order_items i 
    ON m.order_item_id = i.order_item_id LEFT JOIN postmeta p 
    ON i.order_id = p.order_id 
   AND p.meta_key = '_original_order'
 WHERE p.order_id IS NULL
```

Output:

```
| ORDER_ID | META_VALUE |
|----------|------------|
|      201 |        100 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae4792/2)** demo

Comment: This is not quite working.  Its finding all the values where any 3 of the keys are present ('_subscription', '_recurring%', or '_product_id').  It should match only match when a value for the first 2 is present.

I updated the fiddle to demonstrate - [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae4792/1) - the last row should not be returned.